# Unable to use Autocompletebox in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I installed nudget autocomplete toolkit but unfortunately I found it wierd that this control doesn't have enough property to serve as autocomplete. It has ItemsSource but it doesn't show the list of items filtered when you type something. I am also looking for something like textChanged so that I can invoke my service and get the result again and bind the itemsource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my implementation used in [Group Contacts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc):

XAML:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:behaviors="using:MyNamespace.Behaviors"
```

.
.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Searchbox" PlaceholderText="contact's name" Width="250" 
         IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
         IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
         VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="KeyUp">
            <behaviors:FilterContactAction />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Code:

```
public class FilterContactAction : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    string _previousResult = null;

    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        var textbox = sender as TextBox;
        var keyEventArgs = parameter as KeyRoutedEventArgs;

        var noChanges = textbox.Text == _previousResult;
        var deletionOccurred =   keyEventArgs.Key == VirtualKey.Back ||
                                keyEventArgs.Key == VirtualKey.Delete;

        if (noChanges || deletionOccurred)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var viewModel = ResourceLocator.Instance[typeof(HomeViewModel)] as HomeViewModel;
        viewModel.CanSearch = FindMatch(textbox, viewModel.Contacts);

        return null;
    }

    private bool FindMatch(TextBox textbox, ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts)
    {
        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            var suggestionDisplayed = DisplaySuggestion(textbox, contact);

            if (suggestionDisplayed)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool DisplaySuggestion(TextBox textbox, Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact contact)
    {
        var characterCount = textbox.Text.Count();
        var suggestionDisplayed = false;

        var isMatch = contact.DisplayName.ToUpper().StartsWith(textbox.Text.ToUpper());

        if (isMatch)
        {
            textbox.Text = contact.DisplayName;
            textbox.SelectionStart = characterCount;
            textbox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length - textbox.SelectionStart;

            _previousResult = textbox.Text;

            suggestionDisplayed = true;
        }

        return suggestionDisplayed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TextBoxExt control from Syncfusion WinRT Studio has enough features to work as an AutoComplete. It has more than 15 suggestion modes including custom filter option. Hope this helps.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you used. Can't tell you why it doesn't work either. however last year I wanted AutoCompleteTextBox and ended up writing it myself.

you can find it here.
https://github.com/hermitdave/HermitDaveWinRTControls